# Do Java program parameters require a specific sequence?

Tags: parameters

As far as I know there's no required sequence, like `-XX:MaxPermSize` has to come before `-xmx` and `-xms`.

Does a Java program (.jar in this case, started via a console command) have any specific sequence that it has to have its parameters in?

I have a program with specific parameters like `permsize` to allow it to load without crashing, but something is causing it to hang on boot and trying to figure out why.

Edit: I cannot start my game with the -xdebug parameter, even though i have some other information added for a remote debugger ("-xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8000").
When i try, i keep getting the "Could not create the Java Virtuel Machine", and the error log just says "Unrecognized option: -xdebug".

Comment: It totally depends on the program and how it parses the command line arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. These are JVM arguments and there is no sequence required. There must be something else that makes your program hang. What other parameters do you have ?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use -xdebug to see if you get any information regarding the crash. (the order of the -x args does not matter - as was already answered).

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/jrdocs/refman/optionX.html

Comment: I cannot start my game with the -xdebug parameter, even though i have some other information added for a remote debugger ("-xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8000"). When i try, i keep getting the "Could not create the Java Virtuel Machine", and the error log just says "Unrecognized option: -xdebug".

Comment: try to add an env var " _JAVA_OPTIONS " = -Xmx####M where ### is up to you. it is possible that on JVM load all java values are being ignored.  ( i had suggested the -Xdebug to assist in getting better error msgs not as a solution to your problem. )

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not needed or even required for this

Answer (score 0):

You need a capital X, not lower-case: -Xdebug .
But that's only if you need it at all.  This has been deprecated since Java5; depending on your JVM, you probably don't need it at all.  For instance, [for the Sun/Oracle Java6 JVM, this isn't even a valid option](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html).